# utPLSQL: How can i compare two tables?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql, utplsql

Lets say i have table 1 and table 2. Table 2 is the updated version of table one. It can have same or updated structure, columns and data. I want to compare those two tables.

Comment: Are you really using the UTPLSQL framework? Some of your previous questions suggest you were hand-rolling your unit tests. If you are using UTPLSQL please clarify whether v2 or v3 - they have completely different APIs.

Comment: Yes, i'm using utPLSQL v3. I have already found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: If you have found a solution then please post it as an answer, It may help other Seekers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My requirement was to compare columns, data and constraints of two tables using utPLSQL. 
i met my requirement by using native refcursors.

For data comparison:

```
OPEN p_store FOR SELECT * FROM customers@dblink2;
OPEN p_store2 FOR SELECT * FROM customers2@dblink2;
ut.expect(p_store).to_equal(p_store2);
```

For column comparison:

```
OPEN p_store FOR
SELECT
    A.COLUMN_NAME,
    A.DATA_TYPE,
    A.DATA_LENGTH
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS@dblink2 WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'CUSTOMERS') A;
OPEN p_store2 FOR
SELECT
  B.COLUMN_NAME,
  B.DATA_TYPE,
  B.DATA_LENGTH
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns@dblink2 WHERE table_name = 'CUSTOMERS') B;
ut.expect(p_store).to_equal(p_store2);
```

I using utPLSQL V3. If you're using v2 then **utassert.eqtable** can be used.

Answer (score 1):

=> Sample Query to compare the structure of tables (add columns like datatype and other comparison parameters as you need ) here using all_tab_cols:

```
SELECT
    t1.table_name
   ,t2.table_name
   ,t1.column_name
   ,t2.column_name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            all_tab_cols
        WHERE
            table_name = 'TEMP1'
    ) t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            all_tab_cols
        WHERE
            table_name = 'TEMP2'
    ) t2 ON t1.owner = t2.owner
            AND t1.column_name = t2.column_name;
```

2. To Compare data :

   1. You can Use a similar query with join different types of join to compare like left and right join.

      SELECT
       *
      FROM
       temp1 t1
       FULL JOIN temp2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
   2. You can Use Set operations like union ,unionall and intersect to compare further use distinct.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to compare all columns in 2 tables then try below query**

```
select * from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id
```

**But if you want compare some specified columns then try below query**

```
select t1.column,t2.column from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.column,t2.column
```

It should be work for your requirement.